# Codeigniter 3 - Unable to locate the model you have specified

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am aware of the other questions on the platform for this issue however I am having a very unusual issue with this.

I have a model `Company_Model.php` which is being autoloaded in the `autoload.php` and the Class is built like this:

```
Class Company_Model extends CI_Model {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function foo()
    {
        echo 'bar';
    }
}
```

However I am still getting this error when I load the page:

[image: Codeignter 3 - Unable to locate the model you have specified]

I am running on Apache 2, PHP 5.5.9 on Ubuntu 14.04, I cannot find an error log for this issue and now I am baffled, any help would be gratefully recieved.

I have check the uppercasing and all of the other tips from StackOverflow but still no joy.

## Edit

Auto load code

`$autoload['model'] = array('company_model');`

Comment: Can you post the code from the autoload.php where the Company model is specified?

Comment: Try Changing the class name `Company_Model` to `Company_model` and also change your file name `Company_Model.php` to `company_model.php `

Comment: @Uchiha tried this but no joy

Comment: @gabe3886 added the autoload

Comment: @JustinErswell Did you tried changing your filename into `company_model.php ` and the rest of the part as commented

Comment: If [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31337002/2899618) is perfect than whats wrong with the comment @JustinErswell

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use codeigniter 3 you have to make sure your class names and file names only have the first letter upper case as explained here

[Class Naming Style Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#class-and-method-naming)

[Filename Style Guide](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming)

```
<?php

class Company_model extends CI_Model {

}
```

And file name then should be **Company_model.php**

```
$autoload['model'] = array('company_model');
```

If in sub folder

> models > sub folder > Company_model.php

```
$autoload['model'] = array('subfolder/company_model');
```

**If need to call it on controller only**

```
$this->load->model('company_model');

$this->company_model->function();
```

**Sub folder**

```
$this->load->model('subfolder/company_model');

$this->company_model->function();
```

Comment: @JustinErswell why this answer is perfect? what fixed your problem? I see everything same as you did.

Comment: Your welcome just remember In **Codeigniter 3** all controllers and models and library need to have there first letter on class and file name as upper case.

Comment: To clarify the problem was that I had ```Company_Model`` as the class name and the file name was the same, I changed to ```Company_model``` for both class and file and also in the auto load ```Company_model``` and it fired up

Comment: oh yes.File name should contain one uppercase letter(the first one). Btw you can use model name `Company_Model` (more upper case)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your class name and file name should be same and first Letter should be Capital

**Example**

```
class Login extends CI_Model{
//some code
}
```

above code, you can see the class **`Login`** first letter is capital.same name you have save of your model file name like **Login.php** in the model directory of your project folder

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing the class name Company_Model to Company_model and also change your file name Company_Model.php to company_model.php