# Unable to locate the model you have specified codeigniter 3

Tags: php, codeigniter

when i am working with localhost then everything is fine. But When i uploaded in hosting then its show error " Unable to locate the model you have specified"

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: RuntimeException Message:
>   Unable to locate the model you have specified: Stock_model Filename:
>   /home/autorentbd/public_html/pharmacy/system/core/Loader.php Line
>   Number: 344

**Backtrace:**

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
  class Stock extends MY_Controller {
    public function __construct()
    {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper("url");
    $this->load->library("pagination"); 
    $this->load->model('Stock/stock_model'); // My Model name is stock_model.php, is in module folder. 
    }
 public function stock_list($data = NULL)
  {   
    $data['title'] ='Medicine Stock List';  //data title 
    $data['stock_list'] = $this->stock_model->stock_list(); //call model function 
    $data['view_all'] = 'stock/stock_list';  //view file
    $this->templates->version_one($data); //template
  }
 }
```

And My Model name: `stock_model.php`, My Class name is: `Stock_model`. all in under module folder.

Comment: duplicate question.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336621/codeigniter-3-unable-to-locate-the-model-you-have-specified

Comment: Also mind checking capitals with file / folder names, Windows ignores this but linux is capital sensitive. Common error when people try to put their projects live is when not using some constant with file / folder names.

Comment: Dear @atoms Please see this url http://pharmacy.autorent-bd.com/

Comment: Dear bro give correct folder and file name structure please please @killstreet

Comment: Could you update your question and add the file name of the actual model file? Aswell as the class name of the home_model?

Comment: rename stock_model.php to Stock_model.php

Comment: <?php
       defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
         class Stock_model extends CI_Model {
     public function __construct()
      {
  parent::__construct();
  
     }

Comment: `$this->load->model('sock/stock_model');` lower case on here is better but read through my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336621/codeigniter-3-unable-to-locate-the-model-you-have-specified

Answer (score 0):

Please check your file and class name, like if class name is Stock_model then load with "Stock_model" not stock_model. because some server are followed case sensitive.

Answer (score -1):

**CodeIgnitor 3** and further versions are **case sensitive**. You need to define controller as well as model name in **first letter caps form**. So you need to define your model as

```
$this->load->model('Stock/Stock_model');
```